# Images dont scale properly

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scale

My images won't scale the way they are supposed to. As I understood it Android will scale the images down for me if they are put in xhdpi folder, not optimal for performance but should work, no?

This is an example of how I initiate and draw all my bitmaps:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmap(int resourceID) {
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap tempBmp = null;
    try {
        tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceID,
                options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

    } catch (Error e) {

    }
    return tempBmp;
}
```

Then loading it:

```
bitmap = loadBitmap(R.drawable.example);
```

drawing:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(screenBitmap, screenX, screenY, null);
```

I have multiple of these on screen since it's a game I'm developing.

Should probably be added that I have the scaling problem in the emulator, since I don't have any other Androids but my own to test on, and on my own phone it all fits as it should since that's what I'm testing it on.

Am I missing something or is the emulator messing with me?

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap decoding can also scaling bitmap according per screen dpi.
Try to play with this additional parameter (set as true or false):

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

Comment: Do you know if for example `x=bitmap.getWidth()/2` will have the same value after rescale or will it also change? Im not making any sense of this, some things are in scale, some things are not. Some things are position correct, some are not. And Im using the same methods

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

File file = new File(picturePath);// 
Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(file);

Comment: Can you edit and explain a bit please? why do u set size to 70?

Comment: percentage 70 percent scale image

Comment: Does this method scale things automatically according to screen resolution? having a hard time understanding it.